# users command does not show recently added users

Tags: users, useradd

I have created few users:

```
sudo useradd bart
sudo useradd marge
sudo useradd lisa
sudo useradd maggie
```

These users now exist

```
$ awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
blueray
bart
marge
lisa
maggie
```

However these users does not show up on `users` command output

```
$ users
blueray
```

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the `man user` page is very informative:

`users - print the user names of users currently logged in to the current host`

Comment: This also help me understand why `groups` command does not show recently added groups.